# process subarrays asynchronously and reduce the results to a single array

Tags: arrays, f#

**Input** If input is in the form of array of arrays.

```
let items = [|
        [|"item1"; "item2"|]
        [|"item3"; "item4"|]
        [|"item5"; "item6"|]
        [|"item7"; "item8"|]
        [|"item9"; "item10"|]
        [|"item11"; "item12"|]
    |]
```

**Asynchronous** action that returns asynchronous result or error

```
let action (item: string) : Async<Result<string, string>> =
     async {
        return Ok (item + ":processed")
     }
```

**Attempt** process one subarray at a time in parallel

```
let result = items
            |> Seq.map (Seq.map action >> Async.Parallel)
            |> Async.Parallel // wrong? process root items sequentially
            |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

**Expectations**:

a) Process one subarray at a time in parallel, then process the second subarray in parallel and so on. (In other words sequential processing for the root items and parallel processing for subitems)

b) Then collect all the results and merge them into a singly dimensioned results array while maintaining the order.

c) Preferably using built-in methods provided by `Array`, `Seq`, `List`, `Async` etc. instead of any custom operators (that'd be last resort)

d) Optional - If it's not possible to have something within the chain, then as a last resort perhaps convert the `result` subarrays into single array at the end and return to the caller, if that leads to a cleaner and minimalistic approach which I prefer.

---

**Attempt 2**

```
let result2 = items
            |> Seq.map (Seq.map action >> Async.Parallel)
            |> Async.Parallel // wrong? is it processing root items sequentially
            |> Async.RunSynchronously
            |> Array.collect id


Array.iter (fun (item: Result<string, string>) ->
    match item with
    | Ok r -> Console.WriteLine(r)
    | Error e -> Console.WriteLine(e)
) result2
```

---

**Edit**

```
let action (item: string) : Async<Result<string, string>> =
     async {
        return Ok (item + ":processed")
     }

let items = [| "item1"; "item2"; "item3"; "item4"; "item5"; "item6"; "item7"; "item8"; "item9"; "item10"|]

let result = items
          |> Seq.chunkBySize 2
          |> Seq.map (Seq.map action >> Async.Parallel)
          |> Seq.map Async.RunSynchronously
          |> Seq.toArray
          |> Array.collect id
```

Comment: what's the problem with the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let result = items |> Array.map ( Array.map action >> Async.Parallel)
                   |> Array.map Async.RunSynchronously
                   |> Array.collect id
```

Edit: Note that majority of operations defined on Seq can be found in array and vice versa. If you initially have an array you can use array operation all the way down.

```
let items = [| "item1"; "item2"; "item3"; "item4"; "item5"; "item6"; "item7"; "item8"; "item9"; "item10"|]

let result = items 
  |> Array.chunkBySize 2 
  |> Array.map (Array.map action >> Async.Parallel >> Async.RunSynchronously)          
  |> Array.concat
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I intentionally hid the complete picture to narrow down and enforce thinking with this sequential + parallelism, I had problems asking this question around, Please see the complete picture incorporated with your answer, ok with you?

Comment: Awesome. Beautifully done. Yes it's an array, using `Array` versions.